# What's the reason AdSense is not showing Ads on all my pages?

Tags: wordpress, ads, adsense

Ads is not being rendered by AdSense on all my site pages. Though, an iframe with HTML tag is being rendered through DOM and showing reserved blank spaces.

It's happening on some specific URL pattern and sometimes even don't show even a single page of site.

For e.g, Ads are not being served on these pages:

- https://www.stunningautos.com//author/rimjhim-dubey/
- https://www.stunningautos.com//author/rimjhim-dubey/page/1/
- https://www.stunningautos.com//author/rimjhim-dubey/page/2/

I'm facing this problem since more than 2 weeks. Tried to find solution everywhere after Googling and in AdSense community, but didn't find any answer.

Similar issue report I found on AdSense forum. Where not a single satiable answer has been given.

https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/21139711?hl=en

Finally I posted here with a good hope.

Comment: for me also same problem in my blogs

Comment: Same thing here.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? ive got the same issue

Comment: I didn't figure it out using any code change or tweaking configs anywhere. Instead I understood that AdSense behaves differently based on your site popularity and ranking. When my website started getting lots of traffic then this issue got fixed itself (or AdSense started showing Ad on all pages).
This is what I understand! If you figure out something else and think I'm wrong then please also share with me